# Why does 0/1 Knapsack problem need a 2-D array to memoize whereas House Robber problem need a 1-D array?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I'm asking this in reference to Dynamic Programming, I'm a beginner at it. I understood the House Robbers problem nicely and found 0/1 Knapsack similar to it. But I tried to code it up in similar way using 1-D array but it gave wrong answers. The solution had a 2-D array which is confusing me that why is there a need for 2-D array to store the remaining/occupied weight, as during recursion we are already passing the remaining/occupied weight. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def knapSack(self,sackw, weights, values, n):
    # my approach using a 1-D array to memoize
    dp = [-1]*n
    def recur(i, weightleft):
        if weightleft <= 0 or i >= n:
            return 0
        if weights[i] > weightleft:
            return recur(i+1, weightleft)
        if dp[i] != -1:
            return dp[i]
        else:
            res = dp[i] = max(values[i] + recur(i+1, weightleft - weights[i]), recur(i+1, weightleft))
        return res
    
    return recur(0, sackw)
```

The given answer using 2-D array below

```
def solve_knapsack(profits, weights, capacity):
    dp = [[-1 for x in range(capacity+1)] for y in range(len(profits))]
    return knapsack_recursive(dp, profits, weights, capacity, 0)
    def knapsack_recursive(dp, profits, weights, capacity, currentIndex):

      # base checks
        if capacity <= 0 or currentIndex >= len(profits):
            return 0

  # if we have already solved a similar problem, return the result from memory
        if dp[currentIndex][capacity] != -1:
            return dp[currentIndex][capacity]

  # recursive call after choosing the element at the currentIndex
  # if the weight of the element at currentIndex exceeds the capacity, we
  # shouldn't process this
        profit1 = 0
        if weights[currentIndex] <= capacity:
            profit1 = profits[currentIndex] + knapsack_recursive(
        dp, profits, weights, capacity - weights[currentIndex], currentIndex + 1)

  # recursive call after excluding the element at the currentIndex
        profit2 = knapsack_recursive(
    dp, profits, weights, capacity, currentIndex + 1)

        dp[currentIndex][capacity] = max(profit1, profit2)
        return dp[currentIndex][capacity]
```

Test Cases:

1. weights = [4,5,1], values = [1,2,3], n = 3, sackweight = 4. Expected output = 3.

Only this one runs. The rest give wrong answer. They are too big to post here.

Comment: Some example of what you coded, and the inputs/outputs/expected outputs would help immensely in understanding your question. Usually, recursion means you're doing top-down DP, and arrays can be used to memoize that. Without seeing the code, it's impossible to say more.

Comment: @kcsquared plz check now

Answer (score 1):

*"found 0/1 Knapsack similar to it"*

From what I understand, this assumption is incorrect.

In 0/1 Knapsack problem, you have to maximize the value and keep the total weight under a given limit. There's no restriction on the item ordering that you select (basically, no constraint like "you can't select three consecutive items" or so). Since you're maintaining three properties in the DP state (index, weight, value of each item) you use 2D DP.

In the House Robbers problem, you're maximizing the value without having to keep a check on the count/weight of houses robbed. You just have to avoid picking consecutive houses (which can be done using indexes, no additional property needed). So it requires only 2 properties (house value and index), it is done using 1D DP.

A small note on why your 1D approach is incorrect:

Let's say your `dp` table has a value `dp[5] = 10`, which was calculated for a weight of `x`. Let's say your recursively reach `i=5` again, but with a different weight this time. Your `dp[5] = 10` will get returned, which is incorrect because a different weight might lead to a different possible value.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful response sir. I'd like to mention that when I reach the element with weight 10, i.e. 1th index, I'd be returning a function call with i+1 th index and the same weight remaining, which means ignoring the element with weight 10. Also, "maintaining three properties in the DP state", sir we're already keeping track of the weight constraint in the function calls(reducing it as required), then why to use a 2D array when the function call itself has the constraint ? The value of collected item we're adding it recursively to the variable or dp[i].

Comment: If I do it completely recursively without memoizing, I'll use two variables, to store or reject an item and keep adding them up recursively. There also we'll keep track of the weight remaining(constraint) in the function call only, no separate dimension we use. The same thing I want to do with a 1D dp array.